# Can we Initialize ViewBag inside Webmethod in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to call a WebMethod using ajax that will then initialize ViewBag so that I can access this ViewBag in View but after calling WebMethod using ajax the ViewBag is empty.
Please let me know Is ViewBag can only be initialize inside Controller Actionresult? or Is there anyway to initialize it inside WebMethod.

Here is ajax post request that is calling controller's Webmethod.

```
          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: '/Home/InsertScore',
                  data: { Email: Em, Row: i, Answer: 'd' }
              });
```

Here is WebMethod in Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [WebMethod]
    public void InsertScore(string Email ,string Row,char Answer)
    {

     if(Answer=='d')
        {

       ViewBag.m="Hot";

        }
        if (Answer == 'r')
        {
          ViewBag.m="Cold";

        }


    }
```

Comment: `WebMethod` is to let an ASPX page return XML, so you can call it from AJAX. The ViewBag is used during one request to pass data from the Controller to the View. It seems like you're mixing different concerns, namely WebForms and MVC, thus your ViewBag question being an XY problem. Please explain what you're actually trying to accomplish. Why do you have a WebMethod-annotated method in the first place, and not a JsonResult action method or an API controller? The most obvious fix here is "store it in the session", but the overall design is questionable, so I won't post that as an answer.

Comment: Upon closer inspection: why do you have both an HttpPost (MVC) and WebMethod (WebForms) attribute on this method? Which class contains this method? What do you expect to happen when you write to the ViewBag? Do you want the view to update after an AJAX POST?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session instead.

```
[HttpPost]
[WebMethod]
public void InsertScore(string Email ,string Row,char Answer)
{

 if(Answer=='d')
    {
      Session["m"]="Hot";
    }
    if (Answer == 'r')
    {
      Session["m"]="Cold";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please let me know Is ViewBag can only be initialize inside Controller
>   Actionresult?

Yes you are right. If you want get some date via Ajax call you should use this approach:

```
return Json(new { m = "HOT"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and hanlde it on client side manualy

```
 $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '/Home/InsertScore',
              data: { Email: Em, Row: i, Answer: 'd' }
              success: function(data)
              {
                alert(data.m);
              }
          });
```